# Update a column using the value of another column per row

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to update a value in one table based on the value of another table in a one-to-many relationship, where there will be one movie but many reviews

Here's the schema for my tables

```
movie
+----+-------------+------+
| id | reviewCount |score |
+----+-------------+------+
```

```
review
+--------+---------+-------+
| userId | movieId | score |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

And here's the query I'm trying to run

```
UPDATE movie 
SET score = 
CASE 
    WHEN m."reviewCount" = 1 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE ((m.score * m."reviewCount") - r.score) / (m."reviewCount" - 1) 
END,
"reviewCount" = m."reviewCount" - 1 
FROM movie AS m INNER JOIN (
    SELECT "userId", "movieId", score
    FROM review) r 
ON m.id = r."movieId" 
WHERE r."userId" = $1;
```

However, when I run it, I get the same value across all my rows rather than accounting for the score of each review. Is there something I'm doing wrong or a better way to run this query?

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6) you should not repeat the target table of an UPDATE in the FROM clause.

There is also no need for a derived table ("sub-query") to get the values from the `review` table:

```
UPDATE movie m
  SET score = CASE 
                WHEN m."reviewCount" = 1 THEN 0 
                ELSE ((m.score * m."reviewCount") - r.score) / (m."reviewCount" - 1) 
              END,
      "reviewCount" = m."reviewCount" - 1 
FROM review r
WHERE m.id = r."movieId" --<< this is the join between the two tables
  AND r."userId" = $1;
```

This assumes that each user only reviews each movie once (i.e. one row per userid/movied combination in the review table). If that is not the case, the outcome is not predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Last line should have

```
ON m.id = r."movieId" 
WHERE movie.id = r."movieId" AND r."userId" = $1;
```

rather than m.id = r."movieId"